# Asp.NET Core with SimpleInjector Instance registration error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

I'm trying to write an AspNet Api using SimpleInjector.
However I'm having issues with SimpleInjector. When I start the AspNet application after registering a type in the container, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not
> able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: Web.Services.WeatherForecastController Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType: Web.Services.WeatherForecastController':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'MediatR.IMediator' while
> attempting to activate 'Web.Services.WeatherForecastController'.)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Web.Services.WeatherForecastController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Web.Services.WeatherForecastController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'MediatR.IMediator' while attempting to
> activate 'Web.Services.WeatherForecastController'.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MediatR.IMediator' while attempting to activate
> 'Web.Services.WeatherForecastController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

I understand that there is a missing type not registered in the container, however I register the Mediator just before instantiating the Aspnet server

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = LoadConfiguration(args);
            var comp = new AspNetComponent(args);
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
            container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = Lifestyle.Scoped;
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
            container.Register<IMediator, Mediator>();
            comp.Configure(configuration, container);
            await comp.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

In AspNetComponent.cs:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(
      string[] args, IConfiguration configuration, Container container)
        {
            Startup.UseContainer(container);
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("https://0.0.0.0:8080");
                });
        }
```

And my Startup.cs class:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private static Container _container;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        internal static void UseContainer(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddApplicationPart(
                    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WeatherForecastController)))
                .AddControllersAsServices();

            services.AddSimpleInjector(_container, options =>
            {
                options.AddAspNetCore()
                    .AddControllerActivation();
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSimpleInjector(_container);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
```

I have no idea what is the issue, I've been debugging for almost 3 days.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. My advise is to create a new web project using the default VS template, and add Simple Injector's integration as described [in the documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore). When that works, add your required features step for step until it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code registers controllers twice (once in default container and second time inside `.AddSimpleInjector`). Default container comes first and it does not have `Mediatr` registered (we did it in SimpleInjector container only), therefore it fails when constructs controller - it cant resolve IMediatr. Just remove first case of registering controllers.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // comment out first registration of services
    // we keep services.AddMvc() because it is required for simple injector container AddAspNetCore()
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WeatherForecastController)));
        //.AddControllersAsServices();

    // you are doing this in Program.cs
    var container = new Container();

    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, x =>
    {
        x.AddAspNetCore()
            .AddControllerActivation();
        // you are doing this in Program.cs
        x.Container.BuildMediator(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    });
}
```

Comment: I undestand the first part (removing the AddApplicationPart), but for the BuildMediator, It can't find the method ? I guess it's an extension method but I can't find the package?

Comment: And where do I register the controllers ?

Comment: you already register controllers in your code in simple injector (`AddControllerActivation`). And you don't need `BuildMediator` method since your register `<IMediator, Mediator>` for container outside

Comment: Ok I see now. However the controller is located in another Assembly so the URL is always not found. How can I register controllers from another assembly ?

Comment: just tested, looks like the only line you have to comment out is `.AddControllersAsServices()`. `.AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WeatherForecastController)))` can stay. SimpleInjector uses same mechanism for controller discovery. Updated my asnwer accordingly